# Detect misplaced label in figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions

I realized that I sometimes write :

```
\begin{figure}
   ...
   \label{fig:foo}
   \caption{Bla}
\end{figure}
```

instead of:

```
\begin{figure}
   ...
   \caption{Bla}
   \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
```

Which results in wrong reference numbers.

Is there an easy way to catch all these errors?

Comment: Not really; LaTeX is just doing what you tell it to do (labeling the last element that had an associated number generated). There's no way for it to know that you mean something other than what you code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your editor supports regular expressions this expression should find all wrong label+caption statements

`\\label\{.*\}\r*\n*\\caption\{.*\}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used `pcregrep` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to insert systematically the `\label` command inside the argument of `\caption` to avoid that sort of “errors”:

```
\caption{\label{fig:foo}Bla}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Oliver's answer, I used:

```
pcregrep -M "\\\label{.*}\r*\n*\\\caption{.*}" */*.tex
```